# Page scrolling not working with Autolayout enabled

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout

I have the following ViewController:

[image]

It contains two `UILabels` at top, an `UIImageView`, below it a `UITextView` and below this a `UIButton`. I have arranged them using the Interface Builder following the blue line. All of this controls are inside a `UIScrollView`:

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 660)];

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.descriptionText];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.descriptionImage];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.feedNameLabel];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.load];
```

So when enabling `Autolayout` option, I just selected the ViewControler and then "`Reset to Suggested Constraints in Description View Controller`". But when I run the app, the scroll still appears for the entire page, but the only control scrolling is the `UIButton`. When scrolling up it will scroll below the `UITextView`.

I have made the `UITextView` to resize depending on the text, so I want my `UIButton` to always have the same distance to the `UITextView`. For that I have also set `Vertical Spacing` to the `UIButton`, but like this I don't have any scroll to my page.

Using the `Autolayout` for the first time, can I get some suggestions on what am I doing wrong ?

edit:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,660)];
    [contentView addSubview:self.descriptionText];
    [contentView addSubview:self.descriptionImage];
    [contentView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
    [contentView addSubview:self.feedNameLabel];
    [contentView addSubview:self.load];
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 660)];
    //[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 660)];
    [scrollView addSubview:contentView];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    // to resize UITextField
    [self.descriptionText sizeToFit];
    [self.descriptionText layoutIfNeeded];
    self.descriptionText.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: How do you add the controls to the scroll view, programmatically or in Interface Builder?

Comment: @yurish: programmatically, like in the code I posted.

Comment: Do you have constrains defined for the controls? To what view they are linked?

Comment: Well, like I said, I just selected Reset to Suggested Constraints in Description View Controller, so I am not sure what to tell you here.

Comment: Does everything works fine once you disabled auto layout ?

Comment: Select a control in Interface Builder and in Size Inspector look if the contol has constrains defined for it.

Comment: @Malloc: if i disabled auto layout, it works fine, except that if the text view is bigger it will resize upon the UIButton.

Comment: @yurish: yes, every control has multiple constraints.

Comment: So to what view are these constrains attached?

Comment: Well, the UIButton is constraint to SUperView, UITextView to UIScrollView and the others to nothing, I mean just adding space to the left, to the right or between controls next top them, I don't see nothing about ScrollView or SuperView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autolayout is a bit tricky when it comes to `UIScrollView` subviews. I would recommend:

1-Embed all your controls (descriptionText + descriptionImage + titleLabel + feedNameLabel + load) into a `UIView` first, say `contentView`:

```
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,660)];
//add all controls as subviews to contenView
```

2-Add `contentView` as subview of `self.scrollView`.

3-Keep the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of `contentView` to `YES`.

I recommend you read this technical note from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013309).

Comment: I done this, but something went wrong, because my UIImage is now resized and the all screen and I can see the Title Label, and the UIButton on it. No UITextField.

Comment: Make sure the `UIScrollView` `contentSize` is the same width and height as the `contentView` view frame. In your case it's `320,660`

Comment: It is, I also created the scrollView programmatically(320, 660), and added the  contentView as subview, and then added the scrollview as a subview to self.view.

Comment: No, `self.contentView` should be a subview of your scrollView, and not the opposite. so: `[self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];`

Comment: yes, that's what I did and then [self.view addSubview: self.scrollView];

Comment: Can you post your relevant code on how you instantiated the scrollView and following

Comment: I don't see where you set the `contenSize` of your `scrollView` in your code, have you maybe missed it ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42286/discussion-between-malloc-and-vbx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AutoLayout` you don't have to set the content size of your scroll view. In fact, I believe it has no effect at all. It is set automatically from the constraints you are setting up. The trick is that you have to have at least one constraint related to every side of the scroll view, otherwise the content size will be wrong and it won't scroll. So for example, if you would have a really large image in it you would need 4 constraints connecting the sides of the `UIImageView` to the sides of the `UIScrollView`. You can read about this more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013309).